# Possuo 2 problemas que ao tentar submeter o fomulário

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-3.5, primefaces-5.2

bom estou com pequeno problema aqui no meu formulário na realidade seria 2 problemas.

1 - estou usando um autComplete, e dai consigo pegar meu objeto através da busca, só que na hora de submeter meu fomulário ele simplesmete apaga o que tinha completado.

2 - Tenho um tabView com 2 campos requeridos, caso não preencha nada, ele informa um ID aleatório que não consigo encontrar, os meus componente estão com id.

OBS: esse formulário está em 3 arquivos diferentes, segue o arquivo do TABVIEW

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

    <p:tabView>
        <p:tab title="Serviço">
            <br />
            <h:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="checkTipoServico">
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="escapamento"
                    value="#{cadastroServicoBean.servico.tipoServico.escapamento}" />
                <p:outputLabel for="escapamento" value="Escapamento" />

                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mecanica"
                    value="#{cadastroServicoBean.servico.tipoServico.mecanicaEmGeral}" />
                <p:outputLabel for="mecanica" value="Mecânica em Geral" />

                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="suspensaoRosca"
                    value="#{cadastroServicoBean.servico.tipoServico.suspensaoRosca}" />
                <p:outputLabel for="suspensaoRosca" value="Suspensão a Rosca"
                    style="margin-right:5px;" />

                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="suspensaoAr"
                    value="#{cadastroServicoBean.servico.tipoServico.suspensaoAr}" />
                <p:outputLabel for="suspensaoAr" value="Suspensão a Ar" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab title="Descrição Serviço">
            <p:inputTextarea id="descricaoServico" rows="10"
                value="#{cadastroServicoBean.servico.descricaoServico}" cols="100"
                counter="display" maxlength="200"
                counterTemplate="{0} caracteres restantes." autoResize="false" />
            <h:outputText id="display" />
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Observação">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="padding-righ">
                <p:inputTextarea rows="10" style="width:99%" required="true"
                    value="#{cadastroServicoBean.servico.observacao}" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a imagem

Comment: alguém?? up....

Comment: Posta o converter do seu autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - estou usando um autComplete, e dai consigo pegar meu objeto através da busca, só que na hora de submeter meu fomulário ele simplesmete apaga o que tinha completado.

o comando ao qual você esta submetendo o formulário possui algum update fazendo referência para o mesmo formulário? (isso é bem típico deste cenário).

> 2 - Tenho um tabView com 2 campos requeridos, caso não preencha nada, ele informa um ID aleatório que não consigo encontrar, os meus componente estão com id.

Para este caso aqui, da uma olhada nesse showcase https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/outputLabel.xhtml, é o mesmo cenário que vc está tendo, aparentemente você precisa de um outro componente do primefaces `<p:>` que anteceda a o campo `<p:inputTextarea>`.